# Minimizing memory usage in Julia function

Tags: memory, julia

This function is a workhorse which I want to optimize. Any idea on how its memory usage can be limited would be great.

```
function F(len, rNo, n, ratio = 0.5)
    s = zeros(len);  m = copy(s); d = copy(s);
    s[rNo]=1 

    rNo ≤ len-1 && (m[rNo + 1] = s[rNo+1] = -n[rNo])
    rNo > 1 && (m[rNo - 1] = s[rowNo-1] = n[rowNo-1])

    r=1 
    while true
        for i ∈ 2:len-1
            d[i] = (n[i]*m[i+1] - n[i-1]*m[i-1])/(r+1)
        end 

        d[1] = n[1]*m[2]/(r+1); 
        d[len] = -n[len-1]*m[len-1]/(r+1); 

        for i ∈ 1:len
            s[i]+=d[i]
        end 

        sum(abs.(d))/sum(abs.(m)) < ratio && break #converged
                                                                                               
        m = copy(d); r+=1 
    end 

    return reshape(s, 1, :)
end
```

It calculates rows of a special matrix exponential which I stack later.

Although the full method is quite faster than built in `exp` thanks to the special properties, it takes up far more memory as measured by `@time`.

Since I am a noob in memory management and also in Julia, I am sure it can be optimized quite a bit..

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Can you provide example inputs? That makes it much easier to test out.

Comment: `len = 2j+1`, `rNo < 2j+1`, `n` is array of size `2j`, where  `j` can be any integer. So for example you can take `j=5, len = 11, rNo = 5`, and `n` can be a random array of size `10`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think most of your allocations come from `sum(abs.(d))/sum(abs.(m)) < ratio && break #converged`. If you replace it with `sum(abs, d)/sum(abs,m) < ratio && break #converged` those allocations should go away. (it also will be a speed boost).

Your other allocations can be removed by replacing `m = copy(d)` with `m .= d` which does an element-wise copy.

There are also a couple of style things where I think you could make this a nicer function to read and use. My changes would be as follows

```
function F(rNo, v, ratio = 0.5)
    len = length(v)
    s = zeros(len+1);  m = copy(s); d = copy(s);
    s[rNo]=1 

    rNo ≤ len && (m[rNo + 1] = s[rNo+1] = -v[rNo])
    rNo > 1 && (m[rNo - 1] = s[rowNo-1] = v[rowNo-1])

    r=1 
    while true
        for i ∈ 2:len
            d[i] = (v[i]*m[i+1] - v[i-1]*m[i-1]) / (r+1)
        end 

        d[1] = v[1]*m[2]/(r+1); 
        d[end] = -v[end]*m[end]/(r+1); 

        s .+= d

        sum(abs, d)/sum(abs, m) < ratio && break #converged
                                                                                               
        m .= d; r+=1 
    end 

    return reshape(s, 1, :)
end
```

The most notable change is removing `len` from the arguments. Including an array length argument is common in C (and probably others) where finding the length of an array is hard, but in Julia `length` is cheap (`O(1)`), and adding extra arguments is just more clutter and confusion for the people using it. I also made use of the fact that julia is able to turn `s[end]` into `s[length(x)]` to make this a little cleaner. Also, in general when using Julia you should look for ways to use dotted operations rather than writing for loops. The for loops will be fast, but why take 3 lines to do what you could in 1 shorter line? (I also renamed `n` to `v` since to me `n` is a number and `v` is a vector, but that is pure preference).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect. It is a lot more efficient than `exp` now. Thanks for the speed boost tip as well! Where can I read about these tricks?

Comment: You should check out https://discourse.julialang.org/t/array-with-constant-values/51866/8, and probably the performance tips section of the docs. The biggest thing you should look into is probably broadcasting which is a really powerful feature Julia has. by writing `f.(x)` or `a.+b`, julia will apply the function to every element of a collection rather than a collection as a whole. This works for user defined functions, and can lead to really clean code.

Comment: For odds and ends like the `sum` trick, there is no general way to find all of the cool tricks other than ask if you're having performance problems. That said, if you ever feel like something should be doable without allocations, chances are it is.

Comment: Very, very useful! Indeed, I send `len` from my C experience - glad to know its easier to do in Julia. Also, it is so nice of you to go out of your way to make style improvements. I deeply care about writing shorter code. Thank you!

Comment: I think there's a leftover `[i]` outside of the inner for loop.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.